# Is the product of two sets well-defined if one is empty

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set. What is $X\times \emptyset$ supposed to mean? Is it just the empty set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And [more](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_Null) can be said: a cartesian product is empty if and only if one of the two factors is empty.

Comment: My formal proof: http://www.dcproof.com/Siminone.htm

Comment: A side note: This proof also works fine for the Cartesian product of finitely many sets.  For arbitrary products, this statement is precisely the axiom of choice.

Comment: Any of two factors. Your theorem is uncertain about two factors are empty ;)

Comment: Dan's website is not useful for actual mathematical work, and moreover has some bogus articles.

Answer (score 14):

$X \times \emptyset = \emptyset$. In fact, if not we have $x \in X $ and $y \in \emptyset$ such that $(x,y) \in X \times \emptyset$. But $y \in \emptyset$ is impossible.

Answer (score 9):

Recall the definition of $A\times B$: $z\in A\times B$ if and only if $z=\langle a,b\rangle$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. That is $A\times B$ is the set of all ordered pairs whose first coordinate is in $A$ and second in $B$.

If $B$ is empty then there are no ordered pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ such that $b\in\varnothing$, therefore $A\times\varnothing=\varnothing$. Similarly $\varnothing\times B=\varnothing$.