# Symmetry in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets. Prove that $A \times B = B \times A$ if and only if $A = B$. Where do you use that $A$ and $B$ are non-empty?

Comment: $A \times B$ is empty if $A$ or $B$ is empty. See this question: [Cartesian Product of Empty Set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305766/why-is-the-cartesian-product-of-a-set-a-and-empty-set-an-empty-set)

Comment: @FullofDill typesetting notes: `A\times B` produces $A\times B$.  Also `[link name](http://linklocation)` for links.

Comment: One direction is immediate. For the other, consider an element in B and not in A or vice versa and use a pair containing that element. Such a pair cannot be in both products.

Comment: At some point you are going to want to say something like let $a$ be an element in $A$ that is not in $B$... and you can only make that statement (or you would need to qualify it) if you know that $A$ is non-empty.

Comment: How do you read A X B = B X A?

Comment: Every element of $A \times B$ is an element of $B \times A$ and vice versa.

Comment: What does the x represent

Comment: Cartesian product. $A \times B = \{(a,b) | a \in A, b \in B\}$. I recommend reading the section this question comes from before attempting a solution. Not knowing the notation is a sign you're in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

At some point, you'll want to use these two facts:

> 1. $\forall a\in A,\exists p\in A\times B,\exists b\in B, p=(a,b)$
> 2. $\forall b\in B,\exists p\in A\times B,\exists a\in A, p=(a,b)$

However, the first statement is false if $A\ne\emptyset$ and $B=\emptyset$, while the second one is false if $A=\emptyset$ and $B\ne\emptyset$.

The thesis is trivially true if $A=B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

If a in A, there is some b in B with (a,b) in AxB.
Thus (a,b) in BxA and a in B.  Whence A subset B.
As B subset A by symmetry, A = B.