# Is $\mathbb{R}$ a subspace of the Euclidean Plane $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

[image: Functional Analysis: Kreyszig, Page 146]

It said that $\mathbb{R}$ a subspace of the Euclidean Plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. But $\mathbb{R}$ is not even a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. How can it be possible?  Thank you for helping.

Comment: They are not being literal. It is isomorphic to a subspace of the plane.Such as {(x,0) | x is real } with the inherited topology.

Comment: @Alephnull : I fear that a good answer to this question will be longer and messier than that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy My comment is a good answer. But every reader may not understand it.

Comment: @Alephnull: Nitpick (as we used to say in sci.math) --- Regarding "every reader may not understand it", this is not correct (I understand it), as "for all followed by negation" is not the same as "negation followed by for all". On the other hand, what you wrote is probably commonly used enough to fall under the umbrella of being colloquial.

Comment: Authors shouldn't do this, without explanation, the first time it is done.

Comment: @zhw. For the most part I agree with you.  Except, I think if you go way back to the first time we are introduced to cartesian coordinates we are taught about *the* x-y plane as though there were a single universal plane based on a single universal x axis crossing a y axis. And then when we learn of 3D *space* we are told the x-y plane is simply when z = 0 so ....

Comment: I was curious, so I looked through my copy of Kreyszig's book just now (I took a course in 1984 that used Kreyszig's book) to see if there is any prior mention in the book of an "abuse of terminology" convention for a case such as this, and I couldn't find one. So it appears this is an editing oversight.

Comment: This is a functional analysis book, not linear algebra.  It's an easy omission to forgive as far as I'm concerned, especially since the preface indicates the reader is expected to have an undergrad linear algebra background.  @MichaelHardy, I don't understand why a good answer has to be long and messy.  Is there a reason writing down the function $\Phi : x \mapsto x e_{1} + 0 e_{2}$ and proving it's an injective linear map wouldn't suffice?

Comment: @fleablood That is true, but that is when we are younger and in need of help. By the time functional analysis rolls around, we've become adept and desirous of the ways of rigor (supposedly), and we're ready for exactitude. Of course we're always in need of help ...

Comment: Well, I honestly don't remember how the concept of an n-tuple was formally defined for me in the first place.  Somehow I accepted $\{(x_1,x_2)\}=\mathbb R^2 \subset (\mathbb R^2)\times \mathbb R = \mathbb R^3= \{(x_1, x_2,x_3)\}$ without too much trouble.  Perhaps I shouldn't have.  Then again.  If an $n$-tuple is defined an ordered set of points, and a singleton is defined as both the element itself and the 1-tuple of the element and $A\times B=\{(a,b)|a\in A, b\in B$ then ... $A\times \emptyset=A$ and $A\times \emptyset \subset A\times B$.  Is that acceptable to a student?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that Kreyszig's book is fairly elementary, and he even develops all the basic concepts from linear algebra that are needed, so given the context and the level of his book at page 146, the $x$-axis should have been used, or perhaps better, word it as he did but include a footnote along the lines of "Of course, by $\mathbb R$ we mean [. . .]".

Comment: R is a subset of R^2 in a book on linear algebra. I am not young enough however to remember which book it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take as my definition of the vector space $(\mathbb{R}^{2},+,\cdot)$ the set $\mathbb{R}^{2} = \{(x,y) \, \mid \, x, y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ with the operations $(x,y) + (z,w) = (x + z, y + w)$ and $\lambda \cdot (x,y) = (\lambda x, \lambda y)$ with the addition and multiplication of the coordinates inherited from the corresponding operations in the complete ordered field $\mathbb{R}$.  I will prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.  In particular, I will prove that $\mathbb{R} \simeq \{(x,0)  \mid  x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Define a linear map $\Phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ by $$\Phi(x) = (x,0).$$  This is linear since 
\begin{align*}
\Phi(x + y) &= (x + y, 0) = (x,0) + (y,0) = \Phi(x) + \Phi(y) \\
\Phi(\lambda x) &= (\lambda x, 0) = (\lambda x, \lambda \cdot 0) = \lambda (x,0) = \lambda \Phi(x).
\end{align*}
Moreover, $\Phi$ is injective.  Indeed, if $\Phi(x) = \Phi(y)$, then 
\begin{align*}
\Phi(x) = (x,0) = (y,0) = \Phi(y)
\end{align*}
which implies $x = y$ by the definition of (the set) $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.  Thus, $\Phi$ is injective.  Recall that the image of a linear map is always a linear subspace of the target.  In particular, $\Phi(\mathbb{R})$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.  Since $\Phi$ is injective, $\Phi : \mathbb{R} \to \Phi(\mathbb{R})$ is a bijective linear map.  It is immediate that $\Phi(\mathbb{R}) = \{(x,0) \, \mid \, x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.  This completes the proof that $\mathbb{R} \simeq \{(x,0) \, \mid \, x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

If you've read this far, I hope you will try to "draw" the line $\{(x,0) \, \mid \, x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ in the plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (e.g. using Cartesian coordinates).  A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: I am sorry that I am stupid, I still can not see that $\mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ from your explanation. So you mean that $\mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is correct? Could you prove it by definition?

Comment: You are not stupid, mathematicians are lazy.  $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ so the statement "$\mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$" is technically wrong.  You are right to question it.  The intention of the statement is "$\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ in a natural way, for example, by sending $x$ to the point $(x,0)$."  $\mathbb{R}$ is *not* a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$; it is *isomorphic* to one in a very clear geometric fashion.

Comment: But, in fact $\mathbb R$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.  So you answered you can extend $\mathbb R$ to create a space isomorphic to $\mathbb R$.  But you fail to emphasize that in fact $\mathbb R$ is not in fact a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$; only the extension of $\mathbb R$ to $ \mathbb R^2$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.  Hence, you fail to answer correctly that in fact $\mathbb R$ is not, in itself, without the constructed extension, a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Identify $R$ with $R \times  \{0\}$, the Cartesian product of $R$ and $\{0\}$ by the isomorphism $f(x)=(x,0)$.

That is what they mean when they talk about the real line being a subspace of the Cartesian plane.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you are right and as was stated in the comments, maybe authors should not do this without explanation.

Consider the $\mathbb R^2 = $ the $x$-$y$ plane $= $ "the $x$-axis crossed with the $y$-axis" = $\{(x,y)\mid x\in \mathbb R, y\in \mathbb R\}$ or any other way we will introduce this concept to students for the first time.

Now, consider immediately introducing $\mathbb R^3 = $ the $x-y-z$ space $= $ "the $x$-axis crossed with the $y$-axis crossed with the $z$-axis" = $\{(x,y,z)\mid x,y,z\in \mathbb R\}$

Now suppose some well-meaning instructor or some bright elementary student claimed that "the" $x-y$ plane and "the" $x$-axis and $y$-axis we refered to in defining the 2-D plane were the "same" $x$-axis and $y$-axis as in 3D space but with $z$ being restricted to $0$.

Would the instructor/student be right or wrong?  Or would it be a case of "It depends on how you look at it".

Basically the author is viewing $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb R^2 \subset \mathbb R^3 \subset \cdots$ via $\mathbb R^n = \mathbb R^n \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R = \mathbb R^{n+1}$.  In other words, as thought there is *one* universal abstract set of axes, and $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ have the same axes but $\mathbb R^n$ is restricted to $x_{n+1} = 0$.

Is this legitimate?  Is this fair?

Well, sort of.  But.... not really.

It's "clear" that $\mathbb R^n \times \{0\} = \{(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n, 0)\in R^{n+1}\}$ is isomorphic and in every possible sense *equivalent*. And it "doesn't matter" that $\mathbb R^n \times \{0\}$ are not the same thing; in every important sense they might as well be.

But then on the other hand they are clear not the same thing at all.

Except on the third hand; Aren't they?  How was the concept of $A \times B = \{(a,b)\mid a \in A; b\in B\}$ every introduced in the *first* place?  Does "putting two elements from two sets next to each other" make sense?  Is it well defined?

If so what is $A\times \emptyset = \{(a,b)\mid a \in A; b\in \emptyset\}$?  Wouldn't it mean $A\times \emptyset = \{(a,b)\mid a \in A; b\in \emptyset\} = \{(a,*) \mid a \in A\} = \{(a)\mid a\in A\} = \{a\mid a\in A\} = A$?  If not, why not?  Admittedly the "$1$-tuple" $(a)$ doesn't look like the *element* $a$ but if they are different what exactly is the difference?  Can we or can we not define $(a,b)$ where $b$ simply does not exist at all? i.e. if $b \in \emptyset$?

By all logic, $A \times \emptyset = A$ and $\emptyset \subset B$, so ..... logically $A = A\times \emptyset \subset A\times B$.  Thats logical isn't it?

Okay, It feels as though someone is pulling a fast one on us but...  are they?

I'll let you think this out.

Comment: I know that $A\times\emptyset=\emptyset$ by common definition. cf.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305766/why-is-the-cartesian-product-of-a-set-a-and-empty-set-an-empty-set

And I somehow understand the ide of the author means. I just don't agree that $\mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by definition. Could you give me a "right or wrong" answer to the statement of the author made.

Comment: Hmm.... I guess *I* was mistaken in that I thought $A\times \emptyset = A$ and not the empty set but I was wrong.  So I guess that part of my post isn't correct.  The author is assuming for all practical purposes $A \cong A\times \{a\}$ for any set with one element and the set $R^n = \{(x_1, ....x_n)\} = \{(x_1,...., x_n, a)\} = R^n\times \{a\} \subset \{(x_1,....,, x_n, x_{n+1})\} = R^{n+1}$.  That *IS* what the author is saying.  For all practical purposes $R \time\{0\}$ and $R$ *are* the same thing.  .... The only trouble is... it's not technically true....